# How can I get the contents of an iframe without putting the iframe on the page?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the html of an iframe without physically putting the iframe on the page? Can I put the iframe into a variable and get it that way?

Comment: is the ifrmae pointing to page on your domain ?

Comment: It's pointing to another domain, but one that I own.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using node.js (which I would recommend for this), then take a look at [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

As for javascript specifically, you cannot make a call to an external page using javascript (without using hacky methods), as it would violate Cross-domain policy

An untested afterthought, but you might be able to put an iframe hidden through css and then access the content through the document/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php-page with the HTML-content,
Easily include the file with php include:

```
<?php
    include "filename.php";
?>
```

but...why?

Comment: I've already been able to do it via php but ideally I want it to be a 100% javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript to get content from cross domain url. So even if you have actual iframe element on your page, you will not be able to access its elements using javascript. This is called **Same Origin Policy**.

though JSONP is an alternative to your case, you will not be able to access elements inside iframe. You can use Jquery and JSONP to get html of cross domain page

Another option For this scenario is, you can grab the content from server side scripting language like c#, PHP